# Javascript syntax error for slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am transferring my website to my own server, I built it using a free online service with a theme. I downloaded the archive of files however trying to get it to work is giving me errors. The only thing that isn't working is the javascript slideshow i have a syntax error and cant figure out what the problem is.

here is the code:

```
     < script type='text/javascript'>
     (function (jQuery) {
     function init() {
         wSlideshow.render({
             elementID: "401544824517155183",
             nav: "numbers",
             navLocation: "bottom",
             captionLocation: "bottom",
             transition: "slide",
             autoplay: "1",
             speed: "5",
             aspectRatio: "auto",
             showControls: "false",
             randomStart: "true",
             images: [{
                 "url”:”uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/5573326.png", "width":"333",
                     "height": "208"
             }, {
                 "url”:”uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/6952116.png", "width": "400",
                     "height": "250"
             }, {
                 "url”:”uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/116529.png", "width": "400",
                     "height": "250",
                     "link": "/iosapplication.html"
             }, {
                 "url”:”uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/6185044.png", "width": "333",
                     "height": "208",
                     "link": "/puffinbook.html"
             }, {
                 "url”:”uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/6694718.png", "width": "333",
                     "height": "208",
                     "link": "/cyrenians.html"
             }]
         })
     }
     jQuery ? jQuery(init) : document.observe('dom:loaded', init)
 })(window._W && _W.jQuery)
        < /script>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Did you copy over the JavaScript files?

Comment: 1) Format your code so people can actually read it. 2) provide the error message and the location that it originates from.

Comment: Show the error using your browser debugger or add `console.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely, you wrote **”** instead of **"**. use following script.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function (jQuery) {
    function init() {
     wSlideshow.render({
         elementID: "401544824517155183",
         nav: "numbers",
         navLocation: "bottom",
         captionLocation: "bottom",
         transition: "slide",
         autoplay: "1",
         speed: "5",
         aspectRatio: "auto",
         showControls: "false",
         randomStart: "true",
         images: [{
             "url":"uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/5573326.png", "width":"333",
                 "height": "208"
         }, {
             "url":"uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/6952116.png", "width": "400",
                 "height": "250"
         }, {
             "url":"uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/116529.png", "width": "400",
                 "height": "250",
                 "link": "/iosapplication.html"
         }, {
             "url":"uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/6185044.png", "width": "333",
                 "height": "208",
                 "link": "/puffinbook.html"
         }, {
             "url":"uploads/2/0/6/1/20616634/6694718.png", "width": "333",
                 "height": "208",
                 "link": "/cyrenians.html"
         }]
     })
    }
    jQuery ? jQuery(init) : document.observe('dom:loaded', init)
    })(window._W && _W.jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: yeh thanks, i figured before this was the error, the website my site was made on used the wrong " thanks